I can't insert long paths in the "Target" box in Windows 11 shortcut properties (might consider using vbs or batch)
I'm trying to create a Windows shortcut that will be put in my startup folder. The shortcut starts a program (Discord), but with a 1-minute delay. I'm doing this because my (ancient) core i3-2100 PC that I forced to run Windows 11 Pro gets laggy when there are a bunch of programs that open during startup. My custom shortcut will minimalize the lag. The shortcut opens Windows Powershell and runs a command, but I'm having trouble typing the full path (that has some parameters) in the Target box from the shortcut's properties due to the character limit.
This what I'm trying to type into the Target box:
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -Command "Start-Sleep -Seconds 60 ; Start-Process 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Discord\Update.exe' -ArgumentList '--processStart Discord.exe', '--process-start-args --start-minimized'"
I've tried to bypass the character limit by:

Enabling Win32 long paths via Local Group Policy Editor
Setting LongPathsEnabled to 1 via Registry Editor

Unfortunately, all of those methods didn't work.
Is there something I'm missing or should I consider creating a VBS or batch file instead?

I made a string that doesn't bypass the maximum character limit by using cmd within a PowerShell command line (which is shorter because it doesn't need an -ArgumentList parameter).
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -Command "Start-Sleep -Seconds 60 ; cmd /c 'start C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Discord\Update.exe --processStart Discord.exe --process-start-args --start-minimized'"
Unfortunately, it seems like there is no way to bypass the maximum character limit in the Target box. So, the only solution is finding a way to shorten the string.

Just fyi: This isn’t a path, it’s a command (that contains a rather short path). It isn't subject to the Win32 path limit either way, because you’re creating a shell link, not calling a Win32 function. // Maybe create a script file instead, and see if that will help.

LongPathsEnabled does not apply to shortcuts. File Explorer which shortcuts are a part of does NOT support paths longer than 255 characters. As others have suggested that also isn’t a path.

@Ramhound Thanks, I will consider creating a script file

Given that powershell is by default in a location in your path, you can remove the path from powershell and just use powershell ... instead, making it a lot shorter. If you make it start where your discord is, you can also remove the path for discord too.

@LPChip I replaced the full path with just "powershell" but it turned into C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe by itself and cut the string. Typing "cmd" has similar results; it turns into the full path.

Here is the thing, both of those executables are in locations, PATH already has so it’s not necessary to provide a full path to their individual executables

Why downvote? This is a valid question. // No, you cannot create relative (to %PATH% or otherwise) shortcuts using Explorer. Don’t believe it? Try it, check the results. Yes, Explorer truly does arbitrarily limit the combined executable path + arguments field.

The actual shortcut special allows for longer Target paths, but the com interface/Properties dialog impose the limit you've encountered. You can overcome this with binary creation/editing of a .lnk file, but the target path can be broken by attempting to even add a comment via the property to dialogue afterwards. Try putting the entire argument list, starting with -NoProfile, in an environmental variable and make the shortcut target powershell.exe %ArgList%.

@KeithMiller Can you provide an example how to do this?

cmd.exe /C "PING.EXE 127.0.0.1 -n 60 -w 1000 > NUL && "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Discord\Update.exe --processStart Discord.exe""

In the shortcut properties, tell it to start the shortcut Minimized.
See this screenshot.
Alternatively, to make the window completely hidden, write discord.vbs with the following:
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Wait for 60 seconds (60000 milliseconds)
WScript.Sleep 60000

' Run the command to start Discord
WshShell.Run """C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Discord\Update.exe"" --processStart Discord.exe"

I believe it should be enough to simply place the script inside the Startup folder. However, if this does not work as expected, write a shortcut such as this:
wscript C:\discord.vbs

The call to wscript (instead of cscript) makes it run hidden.

It started minimized but not hidden, I'm trying to start it completely hidden from the taskbar. Thanks for trying to help, though. I didn't know a delay could be made using ping.exe.
